# Does the number of columns in a Vertica table impact query performance?

Tags: vertica

We are working with a Vertica 8.1 table containing 500 columns and 100 000 rows.

The following query will take around 1.5 seconds to execute, even when using the vsql client straight on one of the Vertica cluster nodes (to eliminate any network latency issue) :

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MY_TABLE WHERE COL_132 IS NOT NULL and COL_26 = 'anotherValue'`

But when checking the query_requests table, the request_duration_ms is only 98 ms, and the resource_acquisitions table doesn't indicate any delay in resource asquisition. I can't understand where the rest of the time is spent.

If I then export to a new table only the columns used by the query, and run the query on this new, smaller, table, I get a blazing fast response, even though the query_requests table still tells me the request_duration_ms is around 98 ms.

So it seems that the number of columns in the table impacts the execution time of queries, even if most of these columns are not referenced. Am I wrong ? If so, why is it so ?

Thanks by advance

Comment: How your 500 columns table is sorted? And what about the 2 columns version? Can you please share the explain plans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your query is running against the (default) superprojection that includes all tables.  Even though Vertica is a columnar database (with associated compression and encoding), your query is probably still touching more data than it needs to.

You can create [projections](https://my.vertica.com/docs/9.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/ConfiguringTheDB/PhysicalSchema/DesigningAPhysicalSchema.htm) to optimize your queries.  A projection contains a subset of columns; if one is available that has all the columns your query needs, then the query uses that instead of the superprojection.  (It's [a little more complicated](https://my.vertica.com/docs/9.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/ConceptsGuide/Components/ProjectionContentTypes.htm) than that, because physical location is also a factor, but that's the basic idea.)  You can use the [Database Designer](https://my.vertica.com/docs/9.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/ConfiguringTheDB/PhysicalSchema/DBD/AboutDatabaseDesigner.htm) to create some initial projections based on your schema and sample queries, and iteratively improve it over time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I didn't want to go this way, because the table structure is generated, updated and populated automatically, and that I have no control over the queries run against it, but I guess I'll have to dig projection manual creation.

Answer (score 0):

I was running Vertica 8.1.0-1, it seems the issue was a Vertica bug in the Vertica planning phase causing a performance degradation. It was solved in versions >= 8.1.1 : 
[https://my.vertica.com/docs/ReleaseNotes/8.1.x/Vertica_8.1.x_Release_Notes.htm]

> VER-53602 - Optimizer - This fix improves complex query performance during the query planning phase.